# how to prevent NextAuth glitch while reload in Next JS 13?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-auth

i'm using next JS 13 and Next Auth. the functionality is working as expected, but when the app starts/refreshes it shows the login protected screen. in Next JS 12 we used `getStaticProps()` to fetch the session first and load the page. how can i do it in Next JS 13?

the login protected page

```
import { useSession, signIn, signOut } from "next-auth/react";

function Admin() {
  const { data: session, status } = useSession();
  
  return (
    <div>
      {!session ? (
        <div onClick={() => signIn()}>Login please</div> :
        <div> welcome back </div>
      )}
    </div>
  )
}
```

the provider

```
"use client";
import React from "react";
import { SessionProvider } from "next-auth/react";
import { ChakraProvider } from "@chakra-ui/react";

export function AuthProvider({ children }) {
  return (
    <SessionProvider>
      <ChakraProvider>{children}</ChakraProvider>
    </SessionProvider>
  );
}
```

Comment: I might be missing something but AFAIK, `getStaticProps` is not the right thing for fetching `session` because it won't run on every request (unless configured that way). I think you meant `getServerSideProps`. Also, is showing a spinner when `status` is `loading` not a viable option for your app?

Comment: i use `loading.js` of the new Next 13. but it still shows the login before triggering the loader

Comment: `useSession` from NextAuth is not designed for the new app directory of Next 13. The request to fetch the session is triggered inside of `useEffect` ([reference](https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/blob/a72f1b6d21da89b4223542006c865862635c027b/packages/next-auth/src/react/index.tsx#L100-L109)). So, for a split second, the status won't be `loading` and the session data will also be `undefined`.

Comment: so how can i resolve this?

Comment: Until `NextAuth` makes `useSession` compatible with Next 13 (or adds a different mechanism to fetch session for Next 13), you can temporarily move this page to the `pages/` directory. Or, you can create a replacement for the `useSession` hook. Instead of fetching in a `useEffect`, you can fetch at render time (but be sure to use this only inside a server component then). Replicating shouldn't be complex because you can copy paste most of their code and do the required changes in your version.

Comment: but inorder to use `useSession()` i need to make the page client side `use client`

Comment: so what if i made loading screen in `useeffect` with timeout set to one second